# Close modal without redirect

Tags: php, jquery

I have a modal that is created when I click a button. It's content is php - generated because I need to communicate with the server to do some action. Besides the submit button (which works fine btw) I have another button which should just close the modal without doing any action.

I know I can achieve this by encapsulating the button in `<a href="page_to_redirect.php"> </a>`

But I don't want to reload the page, so I'm trying to do it using jquery's close() function. However, the result achieved is that the window closes immediately.
This is the code of the content:

```
<body>
    <?php 
        echo '<form action="action.php" method="post">';
        echo '<p >Are you sure you want to do this?</p>';
        echo '<input type="submit" value="YES"></input>';         
        echo '</form>'; 
    ?>

    <input type="button" value="NO" id="reject">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {          
            $('#reject').onclick($("#delete_dialog").dialog("close"))
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

`delete_dialog` is the id of the modal. I removed the data in the modal to simplify the code, but obviously there are data that are submitted when clicking the submit button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly the jQuery method is `click()`, not `onclick()`, secondly you need to pass your logic to the event handler within an anonymous function. Your current logic means that the `dialog('close')` is called immediately and its *return value* is assigned.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {             
    $('#reject').click(function() {
        $("#delete_dialog").dialog("close");
    });
});
```

Comment: Very good answer. I will accept it in a couple of minutes, once I'm allowed.  Thanks